# jquery like lib in java

Tags: java, jquery, html, parsing

I am looking for a simple lightweight java library that parses HTML. I have looked a lot and there are many options out there. But I cannot find something simple. I really would like to have something like pyquery in python except in java. My requirements are: fast, easy to use and lightweight.

What do I need it for? Not sure if this matters, but I need to index parts of an html documents. So I am hoping to be able to select part of that document quickly and then parse it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used HTMLParser in the past. I wasn't very happy with it. I found tagsoup and jsoup. I really like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org). Haven't used it extensively yet but you can do something like:

```
Elements resultLinks = doc.select("h3 > a"); // direct a after h3
```

Comment: After using jsoup I think it's exactly what I was looking for. I don't understand why after so much googling, it didn't get found. But it has almost every feature that I need.

Answer (score 2):

try groovy. It has a number of "slurpers," which are DSLs for reading in markup like XML and HTML, as well as JSON. [here](http://blog.foosion.org/2008/06/09/parse-html-the-groovy-way/) for example.

Comment: Groovy is a language that runs on the JVM and essentially VERY easy to include in your project. I do not see a reason why this was voted down.

Comment: I voted up for your comment, Ben, but I guess that the guy voted down because groovy is not really java?

Comment: What's "really" java, anyway? It runs on the JVM, written in Java, easy to run.

Comment: @djondal.. thanks. yeah, maybe but it still applies. Either way, really lame to vote down without providing feedback

Comment: maybe they should change SO so we can't vote down without comments

Comment: I have a highly gui sensitive data needs to be parsed then passed to solr. I was hoping for direct java solution. I'll try it though

Answer (score 1):

Use [tagsoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to normalize the HTML into xhtml, and [XOM](http://www.xom.nu) to parse the resulting document. It's not that hard.

XPath will give you easy selection similiar to CSS selectors.

Comment: Looks similar. Tagsoup has a java library you can download, too, but it doesn't give any parsing or finding abilities; it just produces good xml that you can parse.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Jerry which looks very promising
http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/